# How to solve this SSH connection error: Connection closed by remote host Connection closed by xxx.xx.x.xxx port 22

Tags: ssh, server

The server was fine in the morning. But when I came back from lunch, I suddenly found that the server could not board. By the way, my laptop is Macbook air.

The error reported by entering ssh lab in the terminal was:

```bash
> user@.. ~ % ssh lab
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by xxx.xx.x.xxx port 22
```

Entering ssh -v lab@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx again reports the error in more detail as follows:

```bash
> user@... ~ % ssh -v lab@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/.../.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/..../ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/.../.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:22 as 'lab'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/.../.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ...
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/.../.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/zkey/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa ...
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_rsa RSA ...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/.../.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
lab@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Ask how this can be fixed! Thanks! Otherwise I wouldn't have gotten my work done. Orz

I also tried to connect to the server remotely in VScode, but it reports an error Could not establish connection to "lab".

Comment: I don't understand "server could not board". The problem is because you no longer have the proper public key for the target system. Either the private key on the target system has changed or you removed or changed the public key on your system. Did you edit your *~/.ssh/known_hosts* or *~/.ssh/known_hosts2* file? Was the OS reinstalled on the remote system?

Comment: Thank you for your help! "Server could not board" just means "I cannot connect to the remote server". It's strange that I didn't change the private key and the public key...I had tried to delete the ~/.ssh/known_host file, but it didn't work, too. I am also wondering whether it is a problem in my local computer, or in the remote server.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su] or [unix.se]. Also, your second example isn't showing more detail than the first--it's showing an entirely different error. It's not clear which one represents your "real" problem, and I wonder if you may have been connecting to different remote servers in these two examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has already been solved.
I found that there were two strange lines in the *~/.ssh.config* file,
they are:
`Host xxx HostName xxx.xx.xxx.xxx`
I don't know where they came from. But after I delete them, I can connect to the server.